# How can I break a loop in a discord.py command upon execution of another command?

Tags: python, loops, command, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def activate(ctx, quote, delay: int):
    await ctx.send("Successfully activated SpamMode")
    global a
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        await ctx.send(quote)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

So I have this command in my discord bot (made with discord.py), what it does is basically send a message `quote` with a delay between each message `delay` (in seconds) I made it happen with a while loop, is there a way to break that loop upon executing a different command without having to wait for `time.sleep(delay)` to finish?

i.e.

```
@client.command()
async def deactivate(ctx):
    global a
    a = 2
    await ctx.send("Successfully deactivated SpamMode")
```

So basically what is currently happening is that if I try to use this command which stops the previous command from working I have to wait for `time.sleep()` to finish which is what I don't want. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop). You can stop them immediately by using the `cancel()` method

Example:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@client.command()
async def activate(ctx, quote, delay: int):
    global spam_loop

    @tasks.loop(seconds=delay)
    async def spam_loop(q):
        await ctx.send(q)

    spam_loop.start(quote)
    await ctx.send("Successfully activated SpamMode")

@client.command()
async def deactivate(ctx):
    spam_loop.cancel()
    await ctx.send("Successfully deactivated SpamMode")
```