# How to Start and Break a While Loop in Different Functions?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(#*****)
    while True:
        if x >= 5:
            await channel.Send("Hi")
            time.Sleep(1)

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    #Something to stop the while True loop in the 'start' function
```

I would like to know if there is a way to stop the while loop in the 'start' function by writting something in the 'stop' function.

Comment: instead of using hardcoded `True` use external variable that is accessible to both methods and make `start()`'s `while` loop using it. Then change its value to `False` from `stop()` when needed and you should be good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I break a loop in a discord.py command upon execution of another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768225/how-can-i-break-a-loop-in-a-discord-py-command-upon-execution-of-another-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
run_loop = True

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global run_loop
    channel = bot.get_channel(#*****)
    while run_loop:
        if x >= 5:
            await channel.Send("Hi")
            time.Sleep(1)

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global run_loop
    run_loop = False
```

Comment: Why not just return a value rather than using a global?